# Error with fstream object as private member of class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is my class:

```
class Files{
private:
    string fileName;
    bool fileOpen;
    ofstream fObj1;

public:

    Files();
    Files(const string&);
    ~Files();
    const bool fOpen() const{return fileOpen;}
};
```

The Error I am getting:

```
 e:\visual studio 2012ulti\devprojects\oop344 prep\simpleencryption\simpleencryption\files.h(19): error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

I am trying to have the `ofstream` object `fObj1` be a private member of the Files class so that I can operate on it throughout the life of an instance of the class without `fObj1` going out of scope.

The code compiles if I make `fObj1` a public member. Is there a problem with it being a private member?

Comment: can you show where you are using fObj1?

Comment: Are you putting Files instances in some container like vector, or similar?

Comment: The error is saying that some operation is attempting to invoke the copy constructor of `fObj1`, but it is being invoked in a context outside the privately-accessible portion of the class.  Is there inheritance involved?

Comment: No, there is no problem with making the ofstream object a private member.  So whatever your problem is, it's not that.

Comment: whats your code to use fObj1?

Comment: Assuming your code is making *copies* of `Files` objects, since you did not defined one yourself, your class uses the default-copy-constructor and assignment operator. However, said-functions are disavowed when members of the class are non-copyable. The default copy-constructor, for example, will perform a member-by-member copy-construct, and `ofstream(const ofstream&)` (used for brevity) is explicitly *not* supported (they're non-copyable). Likewise with the default assignment operator.

Comment: This is where I use fOBj1:                                            `Files::Files(const string& fName){
 fileName = fName;
 fObj1.open("hello.txt");
 if(fObj1.is_open()){
  cout << "The file has been successfully opened" << endl;
  fileOpen = true;
 }else{
  cout << "The file has failed to open" << endl;
 }
}` @ShahimHafiz